# Cant see the "Format" option in quicklist for a USB device in 12.10.How can I get it back?

Tags: 12.10, usb, quicklists, devices

I am not able to find the **Format** option in the quicklist menu for an external usb drive after I installed 12.10

[image]

How can I et it back?

I tried the quicklist editor in *Ubuntu Tweak* but it does not allow adding any entry to a device quicklist!

What can I do?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem..Any help for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Gparted application for this. If you don't have that installed, then in a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal):

`sudo apt-get update` then press the Enter key and type your usual Ubuntu password (you won't see any characters echoed to the screen for security reasons), then `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Then insert your USB device and open Gparted and select the USB device in the drop-down list at the top right and do the necessary - see screenshots below in order of what is to be done. My USB device is listed as /dev/sdc.

**** Make sure you choose the right device - Gparted will also list the hard drive(s) you have - and you don't want to format those as you'll lose everything on the drive(s) if you format them ****

1. Select the device
2. Unmount the device
3. Format the device with the filesystem of your choice. If you're only going to use this on Ubuntu then ext4 is a good choice. If you will use it on other operating systems then fat32 is a good choice.

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]

Comment: Well I know gparted and i did use it...but i want the option in the quicklist like earlier ubuntu versions!  Thanx anyways :)

Comment: No worries :-) I don't use 12.10 (staying with 12.04 until the next LTS).